# How to use OneColumnFullWidth section in sharepoint site template

Tags: c#, pnp-core-sdk, pnp-framework

I have created a site template using PNP framework:

```cs
<pnp:Section Order="3" Type="OneColumnFullWidth">
  <pnp:Controls>
    <pnp:CanvasControl WebPartType="Image" JsonControlData="{&quot;id&quot;: &quot;d1d91016-032f-456d-98a4-721247c305e8&quot;, &quot;instanceId&quot;: &quot;beb70bd5-7993-4b79-ad1b-2107dec09eb8&quot;, &quot;title&quot;: &quot;\n      Image\n    &quot;, &quot;description&quot;: &quot;\n      Show an image on your page\n    &quot;, &quot;dataVersion&quot;: &quot;1.11&quot;, &quot;properties&quot;: {&quot;imageSourceType&quot;:2,&quot;altText&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;overlayText&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;siteId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;webId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;listId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;uniqueId&quot;:&quot;ed149dc0-5ae8-448b-a7a0-e5f519361804&quot;,&quot;imgWidth&quot;:6016,&quot;imgHeight&quot;:4016,&quot;isFullWidth&quot;:true,&quot;cropX&quot;:0,&quot;cropY&quot;:620,&quot;cropWidth&quot;:6016,&quot;cropHeight&quot;:2028,&quot;fixAspectRatio&quot;:false,&quot;captionText&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;alignment&quot;:&quot;Center&quot;,&quot;overlayTextStyles&quot;:{&quot;textColor&quot;:&quot;light&quot;,&quot;isBold&quot;:false,&quot;isItalic&quot;:false,&quot;textBoxColor&quot;:&quot;dark&quot;,&quot;textBoxOpacity&quot;:0.54,&quot;overlayColor&quot;:&quot;light&quot;,&quot;overlayTransparency&quot;:0}}, &quot;serverProcessedContent&quot;: {&quot;htmlStrings&quot;:{},&quot;searchablePlainTexts&quot;:{},&quot;imageSources&quot;:{&quot;imageSource&quot;:&quot;/_LAYOUTS/IMAGES/VISUALTEMPLATEIMAGE9.JPG&quot;},&quot;links&quot;:{},&quot;customMetadata&quot;:{&quot;imageSource&quot;:{&quot;siteId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;webId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;listId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;uniqueId&quot;:&quot;ed149dc0-5ae8-448b-a7a0-e5f519361804&quot;,&quot;width&quot;:6016,&quot;height&quot;:4016,&quot;cropX&quot;:0,&quot;cropY&quot;:620,&quot;cropWidth&quot;:6016,&quot;cropHeight&quot;:2028}}}, &quot;dynamicDataPaths&quot;: {}, &quot;dynamicDataValues&quot;: {}}" ControlId="d1d91016-032f-456d-98a4-721247c305e8" Order="1" Column="1" />
  </pnp:Controls>
</pnp:Section>
<pnp:Section Order="4" Type="ThreeColumn">
  <pnp:Controls>
    <pnp:CanvasControl WebPartType="Image" JsonControlData="{&quot;id&quot;: &quot;d1d91016-032f-456d-98a4-721247c305e8&quot;, &quot;instanceId&quot;: &quot;af4e84a1-1d4f-45d0-94d9-6c1232271279&quot;, &quot;title&quot;: &quot;\n      Image\n    &quot;, &quot;description&quot;: &quot;\n      Show an image on your page\n    &quot;, &quot;dataVersion&quot;: &quot;1.11&quot;, &quot;properties&quot;: {&quot;imageSourceType&quot;:2,&quot;altText&quot;:&quot;\n      a body of water\n    &quot;,&quot;overlayText&quot;:&quot;\n      Add your text here.\n    \n&quot;,&quot;fileName&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;siteId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;webId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;listId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;uniqueId&quot;:&quot;1730befb-02e2-440d-8239-6d1b7d44218e&quot;,&quot;imgWidth&quot;:5517,&quot;imgHeight&quot;:3702,&quot;isFullWidth&quot;:true,&quot;cropX&quot;:0,&quot;cropY&quot;:12,&quot;cropWidth&quot;:5517,&quot;cropHeight&quot;:3678,&quot;fixAspectRatio&quot;:true,&quot;isOverlayTextEnabled&quot;:true,&quot;captionText&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;alignment&quot;:&quot;Center&quot;,&quot;overlayTextStyles&quot;:{&quot;textColor&quot;:&quot;light&quot;,&quot;isBold&quot;:false,&quot;isItalic&quot;:false,&quot;textBoxColor&quot;:&quot;dark&quot;,&quot;textBoxOpacity&quot;:0.54,&quot;overlayColor&quot;:&quot;light&quot;,&quot;overlayTransparency&quot;:0,&quot;position&quot;:{&quot;offsetX&quot;:0,&quot;offsetY&quot;:0}}}, &quot;serverProcessedContent&quot;: {&quot;htmlStrings&quot;:{},&quot;searchablePlainTexts&quot;:{},&quot;imageSources&quot;:{&quot;imageSource&quot;:&quot;/_LAYOUTS/IMAGES/VISUALTEMPLATEIMAGE7.JPG&quot;},&quot;links&quot;:{},&quot;customMetadata&quot;:{&quot;imageSource&quot;:{&quot;siteId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;webId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;listId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;uniqueId&quot;:&quot;1730befb-02e2-440d-8239-6d1b7d44218e&quot;,&quot;width&quot;:5517,&quot;height&quot;:3702,&quot;cropX&quot;:0,&quot;cropY&quot;:12,&quot;cropWidth&quot;:5517,&quot;cropHeight&quot;:3678}}}, &quot;dynamicDataPaths&quot;: {}, &quot;dynamicDataValues&quot;: {}}" ControlId="d1d91016-032f-456d-98a4-721247c305e8" Order="1" Column="1" />
    <pnp:CanvasControl WebPartType="Text" ControlId="5db27991-a061-4a30-ab9e-bc856633208f" Order="2" Column="1">
      <pnp:CanvasControlProperties>
        <pnp:CanvasControlProperty Key="Text" Value="&lt;span class=&quot;fontSizeMediumPlus&quot;&gt;Above is an image with a text overlay. Click inside the image to replace the text with your own. &amp;nbsp;&lt;/span&gt;" />
      </pnp:CanvasControlProperties>
    </pnp:CanvasControl>
    <pnp:CanvasControl WebPartType="Image" JsonControlData="{&quot;id&quot;: &quot;d1d91016-032f-456d-98a4-721247c305e8&quot;, &quot;instanceId&quot;: &quot;203e35f5-f398-40b0-b246-8e8c9a4e8b9d&quot;, &quot;title&quot;: &quot;\n      Image\n    &quot;, &quot;description&quot;: &quot;\n      Show an image on your page\n    &quot;, &quot;dataVersion&quot;: &quot;1.11&quot;, &quot;properties&quot;: {&quot;imageSourceType&quot;:2,&quot;altText&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;overlayText&quot;:&quot;\n      Add your text here.\n    \n&quot;,&quot;siteId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;webId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;listId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;uniqueId&quot;:&quot;54b4930e-619d-48f5-85ad-0dde8f5aea3f&quot;,&quot;imgWidth&quot;:8832,&quot;imgHeight&quot;:4968,&quot;isFullWidth&quot;:true,&quot;cropX&quot;:690,&quot;cropY&quot;:0,&quot;cropWidth&quot;:7452,&quot;cropHeight&quot;:4968,&quot;fixAspectRatio&quot;:true,&quot;isOverlayTextEnabled&quot;:true,&quot;captionText&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;alignment&quot;:&quot;Center&quot;,&quot;overlayTextStyles&quot;:{&quot;textColor&quot;:&quot;light&quot;,&quot;isBold&quot;:false,&quot;isItalic&quot;:false,&quot;textBoxColor&quot;:&quot;dark&quot;,&quot;textBoxOpacity&quot;:0.54,&quot;overlayColor&quot;:&quot;light&quot;,&quot;overlayTransparency&quot;:0,&quot;position&quot;:{&quot;offsetX&quot;:0,&quot;offsetY&quot;:0}}}, &quot;serverProcessedContent&quot;: {&quot;htmlStrings&quot;:{},&quot;searchablePlainTexts&quot;:{},&quot;imageSources&quot;:{&quot;imageSource&quot;:&quot;/_LAYOUTS/IMAGES/VISUALTEMPLATEIMAGE2.JPG&quot;},&quot;links&quot;:{},&quot;customMetadata&quot;:{&quot;imageSource&quot;:{&quot;siteId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;webId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;listId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;uniqueId&quot;:&quot;54b4930e-619d-48f5-85ad-0dde8f5aea3f&quot;,&quot;width&quot;:8832,&quot;height&quot;:4968,&quot;cropX&quot;:690,&quot;cropY&quot;:0,&quot;cropWidth&quot;:7452,&quot;cropHeight&quot;:4968}}}, &quot;dynamicDataPaths&quot;: {}, &quot;dynamicDataValues&quot;: {}}" ControlId="d1d91016-032f-456d-98a4-721247c305e8" Order="1" Column="2" />
    <pnp:CanvasControl WebPartType="Text" ControlId="0a70cd50-c12d-4dd4-8fcc-f54ff8fdac5b" Order="2" Column="2">
      <pnp:CanvasControlProperties>
        <pnp:CanvasControlProperty Key="Text" Value="&lt;span class=&quot;fontSizeMediumPlus&quot;&gt;Above is an image with a text overlay. Click inside the image to replace the text with your own. &amp;nbsp;&lt;/span&gt;" />
      </pnp:CanvasControlProperties>
    </pnp:CanvasControl>
    <pnp:CanvasControl WebPartType="Image" JsonControlData="{&quot;id&quot;: &quot;d1d91016-032f-456d-98a4-721247c305e8&quot;, &quot;instanceId&quot;: &quot;21d6dc70-e714-4990-992c-556f3c233e74&quot;, &quot;title&quot;: &quot;\n      Image\n    &quot;, &quot;description&quot;: &quot;\n      Show an image on your page\n    &quot;, &quot;dataVersion&quot;: &quot;1.11&quot;, &quot;properties&quot;: {&quot;imageSourceType&quot;:2,&quot;altText&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;overlayText&quot;:&quot;\n      Add your text here.\n    \n&quot;,&quot;siteId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;webId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;listId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;uniqueId&quot;:&quot;d04aa0c8-0444-4f92-ba42-5601d9356b98&quot;,&quot;imgWidth&quot;:4608,&quot;imgHeight&quot;:3456,&quot;isFullWidth&quot;:true,&quot;cropX&quot;:0,&quot;cropY&quot;:192,&quot;cropWidth&quot;:4608,&quot;cropHeight&quot;:3072,&quot;fixAspectRatio&quot;:false,&quot;isOverlayTextEnabled&quot;:true,&quot;captionText&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;alignment&quot;:&quot;Center&quot;,&quot;overlayTextStyles&quot;:{&quot;textColor&quot;:&quot;light&quot;,&quot;isBold&quot;:false,&quot;isItalic&quot;:false,&quot;textBoxColor&quot;:&quot;dark&quot;,&quot;textBoxOpacity&quot;:0.54,&quot;overlayColor&quot;:&quot;light&quot;,&quot;overlayTransparency&quot;:0,&quot;position&quot;:{&quot;offsetX&quot;:0,&quot;offsetY&quot;:0}}}, &quot;serverProcessedContent&quot;: {&quot;htmlStrings&quot;:{},&quot;searchablePlainTexts&quot;:{},&quot;imageSources&quot;:{&quot;imageSource&quot;:&quot;/_LAYOUTS/IMAGES/VISUALTEMPLATEIMAGE10.JPG&quot;},&quot;links&quot;:{},&quot;customMetadata&quot;:{&quot;imageSource&quot;:{&quot;siteId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;webId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;listId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;uniqueId&quot;:&quot;d04aa0c8-0444-4f92-ba42-5601d9356b98&quot;,&quot;width&quot;:4608,&quot;height&quot;:3456,&quot;cropX&quot;:0,&quot;cropY&quot;:192,&quot;cropWidth&quot;:4608,&quot;cropHeight&quot;:3072}}}, &quot;dynamicDataPaths&quot;: {}, &quot;dynamicDataValues&quot;: {}}" ControlId="d1d91016-032f-456d-98a4-721247c305e8" Order="1" Column="3" />
    <pnp:CanvasControl WebPartType="Text" ControlId="d96d37c8-d729-46ae-9cf9-3f4c316ec88e" Order="2" Column="3">
      <pnp:CanvasControlProperties>
        <pnp:CanvasControlProperty Key="Text" Value="&lt;span class=&quot;fontSizeMediumPlus&quot;&gt;Above is an image with a text overlay. Click inside the image to replace the text with your own. &amp;nbsp;&lt;/span&gt;" />
      </pnp:CanvasControlProperties>
    </pnp:CanvasControl>
  </pnp:Controls>
</pnp:Section>
<pnp:Section Order="5" Type="OneColumnFullWidth">
  <pnp:Controls>
    <pnp:CanvasControl WebPartType="Image" JsonControlData="{&quot;id&quot;: &quot;d1d91016-032f-456d-98a4-721247c305e8&quot;, &quot;instanceId&quot;: &quot;aaa96f85-b30a-4927-a87f-7ebe7fdce9ed&quot;, &quot;title&quot;: &quot;\n      Image\n    &quot;, &quot;description&quot;: &quot;\n      Show an image on your page\n    &quot;, &quot;dataVersion&quot;: &quot;1.11&quot;, &quot;properties&quot;: {&quot;imageSourceType&quot;:2,&quot;altText&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;overlayText&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;siteId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;webId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;listId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;uniqueId&quot;:&quot;f46ca4be-b168-4ef2-b91a-dbbde97d31af&quot;,&quot;imgWidth&quot;:4800,&quot;imgHeight&quot;:2696,&quot;isFullWidth&quot;:true,&quot;cropX&quot;:0,&quot;cropY&quot;:633,&quot;cropWidth&quot;:4800,&quot;cropHeight&quot;:1372,&quot;fixAspectRatio&quot;:false,&quot;captionText&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;alignment&quot;:&quot;Center&quot;,&quot;overlayTextStyles&quot;:{&quot;textColor&quot;:&quot;light&quot;,&quot;isBold&quot;:false,&quot;isItalic&quot;:false,&quot;textBoxColor&quot;:&quot;dark&quot;,&quot;textBoxOpacity&quot;:0.54,&quot;overlayColor&quot;:&quot;light&quot;,&quot;overlayTransparency&quot;:0}}, &quot;serverProcessedContent&quot;: {&quot;htmlStrings&quot;:{},&quot;searchablePlainTexts&quot;:{},&quot;imageSources&quot;:{&quot;imageSource&quot;:&quot;/_LAYOUTS/IMAGES/VISUALTEMPLATEIMAGE11.JPG&quot;},&quot;links&quot;:{},&quot;customMetadata&quot;:{&quot;imageSource&quot;:{&quot;siteId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;webId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;listId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;uniqueId&quot;:&quot;f46ca4be-b168-4ef2-b91a-dbbde97d31af&quot;,&quot;width&quot;:4800,&quot;height&quot;:2696,&quot;cropX&quot;:0,&quot;cropY&quot;:633,&quot;cropWidth&quot;:4800,&quot;cropHeight&quot;:1372}}}, &quot;dynamicDataPaths&quot;: {}, &quot;dynamicDataValues&quot;: {}}" ControlId="d1d91016-032f-456d-98a4-721247c305e8" Order="1" Column="1" />
  </pnp:Controls>
</pnp:Section>
</pnp:Sections>
```

But I am getting following error while applying template

> You can't use a OneColumnFullWidth section in this site template GROUP

Please find code snippet I am using for apply template:

```cs
static void ApplyProvisioningTemplate(string targetWebUrl, string userName, string pwdS)
{
    SecureString pwd = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in pwdS.ToCharArray()) pwd.AppendChar(c);
    var site = new Uri(targetWebUrl);
    if (GetContext(site, userName, pwdS, out var ctx))
    {
        using (ctx)
        {
            // ctx.Credentials = new NetworkCredentials(userName, pwd);
            //ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, pwd);
            ctx.RequestTimeout = Timeout.Infinite;

            Web web = ctx.Web;

            ProvisioningTemplateApplyingInformation ptai = new ProvisioningTemplateApplyingInformation();
            ptai.ProgressDelegate = delegate (String message, Int32 progress, Int32 total)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0:00}/{1:00} - {2}", progress, total, message);
            };

            // Associate file connector for assets
            XMLFileSystemTemplateProvider connector = new XMLFileSystemTemplateProvider(@"C:\temp\pnpprovisioningdemo", "");
            // template.Connector = connector;
            var template = connector.GetTemplate("PnPProvisioningDemo3.xml");
            // Because the template is actual object, we can modify this using code as needed
            //template.Lists.Add(new ListInstance()
            //{
            //    Title = "PnP Sample Contacts",
            //    Url = "lists/PnPContacts",
            //    TemplateType = (Int32)ListTemplateType.Contacts,
            //    EnableAttachments = true
            //});

            web.ApplyProvisioningTemplate(template, ptai);
        }
    }
}
```

Why I am getting the above error? Is there anyway to onecolumnfullwidth to work in .net core? I am ready to migrate to another package or framework.